# Azure document Traslation SDK - 404 error

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I've been looking at the Microsoft Azure Documentation for Document Translation SDK C# code-sample:https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/azure/ai-services/translator/document-translation/quickstarts/document-translation-sdk?tabs=dotnet&pivots=programming-language-csharp#code-sample

I followed the C# code example, but a 404 error occurred. I uploaded a Chinese language file in the source container, and there was no file with the same name in the target container. I also retrieved the key and endpoint from the translation service,as well as the SAS URLs for the source and target containers.
I'm sure these are correct because there are no issues when trying the REST API and successfully translated.

```
Unhandled exception. Azure.RequestFailedException: Resource not found
Status: 404 (Resource Not Found)
ErrorCode: 404

Content:
{"error":{"code":"404","message": "Resource not found"}}

Headers:
apim-request-id: *-*-*-*-*
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Fri, 03 Nov 2023 08:20:37 GMT
Content-Length: 56
Content-Type: application/json

   at Azure.AI.Translation.Document.DocumentTranslationRestClient.StartTranslationAsync(StartTranslationDetails body, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.AI.Translation.Document.DocumentTranslationClient.StartTranslationAsync(DocumentTranslationInput input, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\MIS Work\API\consoleApp\batch-document-translation\batch-document-translation\Program.cs:line 29
   at Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

I tried updating Azure related packages and re-uploading documents, as well as updating keys, but the error that appeared on line 29 of the code was never resolved.